# Dc motor that will spin freely when not on

Tags: dc-motor

Is there any micro DC motor that has around 20 RPM and when not powered on will free spin with no resistance? Thank you.  Please leave the name of the motor or link. I’m currently using a Greartisan DC 12V 20RPM Gear Motor High Torque Electric Micro Speed Reduction Geared Motor Centric Output Shaft 37mm Diameter Gearbox

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here, but you need a motor designed for low or zero cogging. Possibly a non-salient rotor. But 20RPM is REALLY REALLY REALLY slow. Even for a MASSIVE MASSIVE MASSIVE motor. Asking a micromotor to rotate that slowly when micromotors are on the very high speed end of things because they are so small seems out of spec. Chances are high that you do not correctly know what it is you need for what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Coreless motors have almost no resistance when powered off. But making a 'micro' motor that only spins at 20rpm is difficult (in general, the smaller the motor, the faster it has to spin). Usually a gearbox is required, and that does have significant resistance. Why do you need this?

Comment: you cannot have any mechanical device that will move with no resistance

Comment: I’m currently using a Greartisan DC 12V 20RPM Gear Motor High Torque Electric Micro Speed Reduction Geared Motor Centric Output Shaft 37mm Diameter Gearbox and it gets the job done but the shaft won’t rotate freely and that’s the problem I’m trying to solve.

Comment: You need something with an electric clutch on the output shaft, this isn't a motor problem, it's a connection one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DC motor that is able to free spin](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/492724/dc-motor-that-is-able-to-free-spin)

Answer (score 2):

To reduce its speed to 20 RPM the DC motor would need to drive a gearbox which wouldn't allow it to spin freely.