# DC motor that is able to free spin

Tags: dc-motor

Is there any micro DC motor that has around 20 RPM and when not powered on will free spin with no resistance? Thank you.  Please leave the name of the motor or link. I’m currently using a Greartisan DC 12V 20RPM Gear Motor High Torque Electric Micro Speed Reduction Geared Motor Centric Output Shaft 37mm Diameter Gearbox And it works perfect but the shaft won’t spin freely even when there is no power.

Comment: Shopping questions aren't allowed, but you could rephrase this as: "is there a type of DC motor that has low free-spinning resistance".

Comment: [You already asked this, and I told you that you need an electric/magnetic clutch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/492695/dc-motor-that-will-spin-freely-when-not-on).

Comment: As already commented, this is a duplicate of your earlier question: "[Dc motor that will spin freely when not on](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/492695/dc-motor-that-will-spin-freely-when-not-on)". Deliberate duplicate questions are not welcome here, therefore voting to close this duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Most slow motors are gear motors and so there will always be the friction of the gear train. gear trains that use spur gears amd planetary gearboxes are to be preferred over worm gears as worm gears have higher friction, especially when back-driven.

Reluctance stepper motors have no permanent magnets or brushes, and so, will spin freely when unpowered. you will need a stepper motor driver.

universal motors have no permanent magnets but they do have brushes so they will have more friction, but still spin fairly freely when unpowered.

Combining your existing motor with an elecromagnetic clutch may be worth considering too.